# React Native Router Flux - How to call Scene's method

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I  want to call a function inside a Scene's component when I press the right button of a navigation bar.

In parent:

```
<Router
        style={routerStyle.router}
        navigationBarStyle={navBarStyle.navBar}
        titleStyle={navBarStyle.navTitle}
        leftButtonStyle={navBarStyle.leftButtonStyle}
        drawerImage={hamburgerIcon}>
    <Scene
        key='History'
        component={History}
        title='History'
        type='reset'
        rightButtonImage={mailIcon}
        onRight={this.sendMail} <-- ON THIS
        rightButtonStyle={navBarStyle.rightButtonStyle}
        rightButtonIconStyle={navBarStyle.rightButtonIconStyle} />
</Router>
```

In child (History.js):

```
openModal() {
  this.setState({modalVisible: true}); <-- DO THIS
}
closeModal() {
  this.setState({modalVisible: false});
}
```

Comment: How about using Actions.History({ modalVisible: true }) or Actions.refresh({ modalVisible: true}) but that is setting it to prop. Then, you would watch for a change in componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: It works! Particularly I fixed it with
`sendMail() {
        Actions.refresh();
}` in my Router and
`componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.toggleModal();
  }

  toggleModal() {
    this.setState({modalVisible: !this.state.modalVisible});
  }`
in the Scene, please post an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Actions.refresh to refresh props of active scene. I have used it as an escape hatch when stuck with this router package.

Be aware of when and why componentWillReceiveProps so you don't call toggleModal unintentionally, though.